# Scrum got specific ways for testing software?

Tags: testing, scrum, methodology, extreme-programming

When reading [Scrum Guide](http://www.scrum.org/Scrum-Guides), as the official text for scrum, I find out there is no specific solution to provide software testing in scrum. (the only hint is on page15)

I'm a little vague on whether scrum is considered a software development methodology or not?
If it is not, then how come some of its practices opposes *Extreme Programming*?
(I know that in scrum guide, the author notes that scrum is a framework not a methodology, but still I'm not pretty clear on that)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Scrum is designed to help manage change in the project life cycle so that the customer can get what they need while allowing the team to develop the product effectively.

It leaves the actual implementation for how to go about achieving those goals open to the team, which is where methodologies like XP come into play.

It's better to look at Scrum as a software development **management** philosophy than as a software development methodology.  The last paragraph on page 15 brings this forward, emphasizing that Scrum works well as a container for other techniques, methodologies, and practices.